# Open specific panel of a jQuery Accordion that is enqueue via WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**What I need to do:**
My client needs a jQuery UI Accordion with 4 panels on his wordpress page. The first panel displays a search form, the second panel displays the results of the search form after a search has been carried out, the third panel contains detailed data concerning each search result and the forth panel contains general help/information about the search form. 
The search is supposed to be done via an AJAX request.

**How I am doing right now:**
This is basic html outline (included in wordpress by the means of a page template):

```
<div class="sws-accordion">
    <h2>...</h2>
    <div>
        <form id="ajax-request" action="javascript:requestForm('x12ldrty','ajax-request');">
            ... 
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <h2>...</h2>
    <div>...</div>
    <h2>...</h2>
    <div>...</div>
    <h2>...</h2>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Enqueue the necessary javascript files in wordpress:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-accordion' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'initiate-jquery-accordion', ‘...', array('jquery-ui-accordion'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', '...', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-accordion', 'initiate-jquery-accordion'));
```

The jQuery Accordion is then called the following way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( ".sws-accordion" ).accordion({ ... });
});
```

The ajax file has the following outline:

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
var requestObject = opacRequestObject();

function requestObject(){
    browser = navigator.appName;
    if ( browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" )
        requestObjectType = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else 
        requestObjectType = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    return requestObjectType;
}

...
```

**The problem that I am facing:**
Everything is working fine, except that I cannot trigger the accordion to open the right panels. I first tried to open the right panels the following way:

```
jQuery( ".sws-accordion" ).accordion( 'activate' , 1 );
```

... however I receive the following error message:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'activate'

My second idea was to trigger a click event on the desired accordion panel in order to avoid the error above. I did this the following way:

```
jQuery(".sws-accordion h2:nth-child(1)").trigger('click');
```

This method opens a panel however not the panel that it should. Long story short, I feel like I am doing something wrong but somehow the solution won’t come to my mind. Any ideas how to address the issue?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you call the accordion function before the document is ready. Don't know where you located this piece of code but maybe try this in a document ready?

Comment: Trigger click should work. You just need to make sure you are targeting the  right panel. Which panel are you trying to target, the first, second, third or fourth?  This might help you find the right selector: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp